# get_theme_mod(); returns nothing

Tags: customization, themes, theme-customizer

I am having trouble with my customize field in WordPress. The field shows up fine in the customize section of WP but it just does not echo out.

```
<p> <?php echo get_theme_mod('copyright_details'); ?> </p>
```

functions.php code:

```
function limus_customize_register( $wp_customize )
{
   //copyright
    $wp_customize->add_section('limus_copyright', array(
        'title' => __('Copyright Details', 'limus'),
        'description' => 'Add/Edit copyright information'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_setting('copyright_details', array(
        'default' => '&copy; 2000-2013 Limus Design Inc. All Rights Reserved.'
    ));
    $wp_customize->add_control('copyright_details', array(
        'label' => __('Copyright Information', 'limus'),
        'section' => 'limus_copyright',
        'setting' => 'copyright_details'
    ));
}
add_action( 'customize_register', 'limus_customize_register' );
```

Comment: I've run your code seems to work fine. Have you tried enabling debug?

Comment: I have enabled debug from wp-config.php but I see no errors...

Comment: Ah I see what was happening for me it only shows up when your viewing the site via `/wp-admin/customize.php`

Comment: Yes, I mentioned that in the post. Just the output is not coming out...

Comment: Have you saved it, know that sounds obvious but the default values are only place holders, won't actually load till you've altered and saved them. Just tried that and seems to be working now

Comment: WOW!, I can't believe all that struggle was because I didn't click save! crazy lol. Thanks a lot it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

If `get_theme_mod()` is loading in the customize section, but not on site, it's probably because you haven't saved and published the field. Try altering a field and clicking 'Save & Publish'.